# Bow Tie antennas impedance

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, antenna-system, phased-array, parallel-dipole

I see on the internet that a radio amateur made bowtie antennas for transmitting and receiving on the 2 meter and 10 meter bands. They produced very good SWR bandwidth when fed with 50-$\Omega$ coax. Why, then, are bow tie antennas for UHF TV connected to 75-$\Omega$ coax through a 300-$\Omega$:75-$\Omega$ stepdown balun?

Commercial 4-bay bow tie antennas connect the feedpoints of the bowties with ~14ga solid conductors and feed the antenna through a 300-$\Omega$:75-$\Omega$ stepdown balun. If the impedance of a single bow tie is close to 50-$\Omega$ or 75-$\Omega$, then connecting four of them with half wave wires should result in an impedance around 12.5-$\Omega$ or 18.75-$\Omega$, which is a very poor match to the 300-$\Omega$ input impedance of the balun. This situation would be even worse for an 8-bay antenna. How do these antennas work?

Comment: Please tell us where you found the amateur and commercial antennas so we can address your specific questions.

Comment: Hello Robert and welcome to the site! I believe that I know the answer, but I would first like to see what these look like. Please provide either photos or links so that we can help you.

Comment: I looked at a couple of commercial UHF TV 4-bay bowtie antennas. Are you sure the feedline is connected to a transformer? It looks like it might be a splitter/combiner.

Answer (score 2):

A **single** bowtie dipole *does* have an impedance of about 50 ohms. *However*, stacking multiple dipoles with a properly-designed phasing system can change that.

Here's a TV antenna that I made and use, with four phased bowties. Notice the phasing lines running between them. At the feedpoint where the 4:1 balun is, the impedance is about 300 ohms.

[image: Phased dipole array]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91578/discussion-on-answer-by-mike-waters-bow-tie-antennas-impedance).

Answer (score 0):

A bowtie is in fact a full wave dipole so it's impedance
is very high which is why they require a 4 to 1 balun.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site! Center-fed full-wave dipoles do indeed have a high feedpoint impedance; but I always assumed that they were just broadband half-wavelength dipoles. Also, the pattern of a full-wavelength dipole would have a few more nulls and lobes.